# Some apps stopped working after update

Tags: updates

After updating the GNOME on Ubuntu 20.04, some apps like Kleopatra (GPG) and Yubico Authenticator (snap) stopped working. It just does not initialize.

u

```
bioath-desktop
Gtk-Message: 14:29:45.215: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open nouveau (search paths /snap/yubioath-desktop/7/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open nouveau (search paths /snap/yubioath-desktop/7/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast (search paths /snap/yubioath-desktop/7/gnome-platform/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri)
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)
```

Already tried to reinstall the appmenu-gtk-module by `$ sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module` but still not working. Same issue.

Comment: The Yubico Auth app is now working aftersudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall  
sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

The Yubico Auth App (Snap) came back to work after updating the Nvidia driver

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
sudo reboot
```

The problem was on the Nvidia driver. Still trying to find how to get Kleopatra (PGP) work again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Yubico Authenticator suddenly not working on Ubuntu 20.04 on a MacbookPro 14,3 [(15-inch, 2017)](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP756?locale=en_US). I was completely puzzled until I saw this post. This laptop has a Radeon Pro 560 graphics card and I had recently installed the proprietary drivers from AMD's `amdgpu-install` package, version 21.40.1.40501-1337797. This post helped me remember that recent changer. After running `amdgpu-uninstall` and rebooting, Yubico Authenticator worked again.

I did not have `kleopatra` installed on this laptop. All I can say about that is that after Yubico Authenticator was working again, I installed `kleopatra` and `scdaemon` and `kleopatra` worked straight away.